# Android handle when app closed from recents

Tags: android, performance

Hi I am updating my db with that of the server on app startup and maintaining the server(db) version in shared preference. When the app is closed from recents, the process stop abruptly without any callbacks. Could anyone suggest a possible solution to maintain correct version that was updated, if app terminates between setTransactionSuccessful and  editor.putInt.

```
 // create a http url connection and get the inputstream            
 InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 String readLine = null;
 db.beginTransaction();
 while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

   // read a line and insert the record into table
    db.execSQL(readLine);
 }
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 db.endTransaction();

 // save the latest db version from the server in shared preference.
 // if app closed from recents need to maintain the last version updated from server
 editor.putInt("db_version", 6).commit();
```

Comment: You can use a syncadapter to sync your server db with your app db. Or if you want to trigger a update once use intentservice and update db.

Comment: Are you doing this with a service then?

Comment: @Raghunandan i am loooking into sync adapter as you said. Tried with intentservice and again service stops without any callbacks to handle.

Comment: @Maghesh intent service does the job and stops by itself. What callbacks are you expecting??. if you are pulling data form your server db and updating local db with intent service it should pull data update db and stop.

Comment: @DroidChris Not with service but with intentservice, does this make a difference?

Comment: That depends, how is the service started?